# Netlogo hatch - inherits breed

Tags: netlogo

In the following code , when we perform `hatch 1` , which breed has a new turtle -`stars` ? Or it doesn`t have a breed - only inherits `last-one?` variable

```
breed [stars a-star]
    stars-own [
      last-one?
    ]

    create-stars 1
      [
        set color brown
        set heading 0
        hatch 1
        [
          set color green fd 1
          set last-one? false ;; don't remember
        ]
      ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `hatch`, the new turtle has exactly the same values for all its attributes as the parent. That includes `breed`, which is an attribute that is automatically owned by the turtle (much like size, x-cor etc). Here's a slightly expanded version of your code to show you your answer, but also to show how to use `breed` as an attribute directly.

```
breed [stars a-star]
stars-own [
  last-one?
]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-stars 1
  [ set color brown
    set heading 0
    hatch 1
    [ set color green fd 1
      set last-one? false ;; don't remember
    ]
  ]
  type "Number of stars: " print count stars
  type "Number of other turtles: " print count turtles with [breed != stars]
end
```